# Moving existing configuration settings over when upgrading executable

Tags: .net, wpf, configuration

I'm distributing a wpf .net executable to internal customers.  I'm saving their preferences to a configuration file that's automatically written to a unique folder in the Temp directory, using the .NET Configuration class.  When I distribute the newest .exe, it creates a new unique folder under Temp, and starts the configuration settings from scratch.  There are two config files: 1 for global app settings, and 1 for each specific data set.

How can I make the settings from the previous version get moved into the new version, so the users don't have to lose their settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: On startup, I look at the directory under %localappdata% where my configuration files are being saved.  I check version numbers to see if the current version is newer than any others that have already been saved.  Then I just copy from the old directory to the new directory.  For backwards compatibility, I cannot remove any old settings from the configs; I can only deprecate them.  In addition, I cannot mark any new settings as "required" in the configuration.

Actually, now that I'm typing this out, I'm realizing that perhaps the reason I haven't found a more generic approach is because the Configuration system has no way to know if you've messed up backwards compatibility with previous executables.